# Porting jdk1.6 compiled jar on android

Tags: android, jar, porting, java-6

is there any direct way to port the jdk 1.6 jar file in android project?

We have ID card reader jar file and its dependent jar file which built using jdk1.6.

is there any possibility use these jars as it is on android platform?

Answer (score 0):

Android supports language features from Java 6, and virtually the entire core library (there were some omissions fixed in API 9, and 19).

You just use the library compiled for Java 6 directly. There is no porting.
In fact, dex actually accepts Java 7 bytecode!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put it to `libs` folder of Your project. But if this jar use classes that not supported by android platform You will recieve something like `ClassNotFoundException`.